# Prove that the dimension of span of a complex number is less than degree to the polynomial which it's a solution to

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

> If $d\in \mathbb {C}$ such that $p(d)=0$ for some polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$, then letting $\mathbb C$ be a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ we consider the subspace $G=$span$\{1,d,d^2,...\}$.

How would I show that $\dim G \leq n$, and that $G$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$?

I'm not sure if should compute the dimension of $G$ directly or if there's some other nifty trick I could use to compare it with $n$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $p(d) = a_0 + a_1 d + \ldots + a_n d^n = 0$ is precisely a linear dependency between $1, d, \ldots, d_n$, and since $a_n \ne 0$, $d^n = a_n^{-1}(-a_0 - a_1 d - \ldots - a_{n-1} d^{n-1}) \in span(1, \ldots, d^{n-1}) $. Same relation allows you to express $d^k$ for $k > n$ as a linear combination of $1, \ldots, d^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The fact that $p(d) = 0$ shows that the elements $\{1,d,\dots,d^{n-1},d^n\}$ are linearly dependent as vectors in $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$.

With Euclidean division (i.e. "long division of polynomials"), we could then write $d^{k}$ as a linear combination of elements from $\{1,d,\dots,d^{n-1}\}$ for arbitrary $k\geq n$.